# QWebView doesn't notify me when it's url changed

Tags: html, qt, signals-slots, qwebview

I have a `QWebView` and set its content with

```
setHtml( "html-code-here", QUrl( "file:///place/where/some/resources/are");
```

I placed a submit button on the website to send a form to action="".
but the widget isn't emitting the `urlChanged(QUrl)` anymore.

Actually this happens since I put `"file://"` before the beginning of the url.
With the `"file://"` prepended it loads all images just fine, but it does not emit the `urlChanged()` signal when I click the submit button.
If I skip the `"file://"` it doesn't load the resources, but emits the `urlChanged()` as expected.

How can I achieve both, loading images + get notified when changing the url?